# Creating a array of pointers to arrays of class T

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make my own table class with dynamic arrays and without using vectors. I understand that

```
T** values = new T* [rows];
```

creates an array of pointers, or a pointer of pointers. I'm not sure how to initialize a new array for each pointer though. I initially thought it should be

```
for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    values[x] = new T [columns];
```

but it also looks wrong because I'm not using any asterisks in that code. So I thought about it again and now I think I might have to use a new pointer to iterate through the pointers in the array. I don't really know the code for it though. I want to say that it's

```
T* pointer;
for (pointer = values; pointer < values+rows; pointer++)
    *pointer = new T [columns];
```

I also don't know how to set the values inside the array that is being pointed to. I think *values points to the array of pointers, and **pointers points to the array of values. I'm not sure how to specify which array I want though.. would it just be something like **values[0][0] = T to set the value inside the first value of the array pointed by the first pointer?

Comment: "I'm not using any asterisks in that code" - there's one hidden in `values[x]`, which is equivalent to `*(values + x)`.

Comment: `T** values = new T* [rows * columns];`
Works for me

Comment: @LordAro That allocates too much memory. You only need `rows` pointers.

Comment: @LordAro Yes, you should allocate `rows` pointers in the top level and an array of `columns` entries in each row.

Comment: @interjay I'm not sure how that's different, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike Seymour stated in comments, your dereferencing asterisk is hidden beneath `operator[]`, and code

```
values[x]     = new T [n];
```

is equivalent to

```
*(values + x) = new T [n];
```

So, to access an element you don't need to dereference again:

```
**values[0][0] = T
```

but simply

```
  values[0][0] = T
```

---

Consider also, the design, where you don't even need an array of arrays, but only a single array:

```
T* values = new T [columns * rows];
```

That you will access simply by calculating index, something like:

```
values[y * rows + x]
```

---

Worth saying, that even for learning purposes, it is better to use `std::vector` there. If you totally inclined on own solutions, write your own dynamic array class (featuring [RAII](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom). Table class with raw `operator new` and raw pointers either will be [non-excepton safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) and prone to leaks, or will include some parts of dynamic array class here and there ([duplication of code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and violation of the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Comment: @Jarod42, anatolyg Thanks! Fixed. That's was too rapid copy-paste ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
T** values = new T* [rows];

for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    values[x] = new T [columns];
```

is valid

If you want to use the second record then the code will look as

```
T** values = new T* [rows];

for ( T **ptr = values; ptr != values + rows; ++ptr )
    *ptr = new T [columns];
```

`values[0]` is equivalent to `*values`

To initialize values you should use two loops (though you can use only one loop but the code will be less readable)

```
for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
   for ( int j = 0; j < columnds; j++ ) values[i][j] = SomeValue;
}
```